# Как в базе mysql искать определенную статью по тегам?

Tags: php, mysql

Какой тип данных в ячейке, где лежат теги?

В базе mysql много статей в таблице (статья - это есть много полей - имя автора, текст, дата и еще хочу ввести поле тэги). И вот, например, есть ссылка на странице: называется php и по щелчке на ней я хочу, чтобы в новом окне выводились статьи именно с этим тегом.

А что делать если у статьи много тегов: например php, mysql и др...

Например, я ввожу в таблице поле tags... вот я не знаю, какого типа должны быть данные в этой ячейке? Как писать их там (эти теги)? Через запятую или как?

И как потом из такого большого количества тегов дать программе понять, что в строке тегов есть нужный и нужно выводить именно эту статью?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как вариант, можно создать таблицу тегов и хранить их там, а пользователю предоставлять выбор тегов из нее, потом селектом выбрать из БД статьи в тексте которых встречается этот тег, или в имени.
или каждой статье выделить еще одну колонку в бд, для хранения ее тегов, тогда по ней сравнивать с пользовательскими тегими.

Answer (score 5):

Используйте такую структуру ( псевдо-код ) - и думаю будет понятно как достигнуть рез-та:

```
Topic: {
  id: int,
  text: text,
  title: varchar(255)
}

Tag: {
  id: int,
  name: varchar(255) unique
}

TopicTag: {
  topic_id: int ForeignKey_Topic_id,
  tag_id: int ForeignKey_Tag_id
}
```

ИМХО: Есть ещё альтернативные названия ( опечатки, etc ) тегов. Логично было-бы при вводе использовать доп. таблицу:

```
TagAlternative: {
   tag_id: int ForeignKey_Tag_id,
   name: varchar(255) unique
}
```

Comment: этот вариант наиболее правилен из 2х

Comment: Спасибо большое, timka_s! буду пробовать)